# Item not being pulled from array after navigating away from and back to page in Meteor app

Tags: mongodb, meteor, coffeescript

So in my Meteor app a user can add themselves to a race or remove themselves too. See below code from my Meteor.methods:

```
update_users_array: ( id, user ) ->

    if RaceList.find( _id: id, users: $elemMatch: _id: user._id ).fetch().length > 0

        RaceList.update id, $pull: users: user

    else

        RaceList.update id, $push: users: user
```

and here is the template events helper to call this method:

```
Template.race.events

    'click .join-race-btn': ( event ) ->

        Meteor.call 'update_users_array', @_id, Meteor.user()
```

This is working ok as long as the user doesn't navigate away from the page but as soon as they leave the page and return and try to remove themselves it isn't working anymore. The code is being executed but the user is not being removed.

Really not sure where I'm going wrong here so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure why this is failing. It could be because you are storing user objects instead of ids, and their fields must be exactly equal in order for the update to work. I'd **strongly** recommend reworking your schema to use an array of ids instead of objects. It's more space efficient, avoids equality problems on removal, and is generally best practice.

I would rewrite the method as follows:

```
update_users_array: (id) ->
  # ensure id is a string
  check id, String

  # you must be logged in to call this method
  unless @userId
    throw new Meteor.Error 401, 'You must be logged in'

  # fetch the RaceList we are about to modify
  raceList = RaceList.findOne id

  # ensure this is a valid list
  unless raceList
    throw new Meteor.Error 404, 'The list was not found'

  if _.contains raceList.users, @userId
    # remove this user from the list
    RaceList.update id, $pull: users: @userId
  else
    # add this user to the list and prevent duplicates
    RaceList.update id, $addToSet: users: @userId
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @David Weldon. I'll try to implement this now and see if the problem persists. I was adding the whole user object because I wanted access to their profile information but now that I think about it, that was totally unnecessary when I can just use their Id's to get their info... Silly! Thanks again

Comment: Worked like a charm : )